# Explicit description of graded (counital) cofree cocommutative coalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, exterior-algebra, divided-powers

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p \neq 2$, and $V = \oplus V_{n}$ be a graded vector space over $k$.

Then, can one compute the graded (counital) cofree cocommutative coalgebra $C(V)$ cogenerated by $V$?

The cases in which I am interested are:

(i) the case $V$ is concentrated in degree $1$.

I think $C(V)$ is just the exterior coalgebra $\Lambda^{\bullet}(V_{1})$, but I do not know how to prove it.

(ii) the case $V$ is concentrated in degree $2$.

Is it $\Gamma ^{\bullet /2}(V_{2})$? (where $\Gamma ^{\bullet}$ denotes the divided power Hopf $k$-algebra generated by $V_{2}$).

Please give me any advice or reference.